# How to get the _visible height_ of a TextFlow inside a ScrollPane, not its text's height?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Extract from the FXML (note: JavaFX 8):

```
<Tab text="Parse tree" closable="false">
    <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5">
        <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" orientation="VERTICAL">
            <TreeView fx:id="parseTree" editable="false"/>
            <!-- TODO: replace with something else -->
            <TextArea fx:id="parseNodeDetails" editable="false"
                style="-fx-font-family: monospace"/>
        </SplitPane>
        <BorderPane>
            <top>
                <ToolBar>
                    <Label fx:id="textInfo"/>
                </ToolBar>
            </top>
            <center>
                <ScrollPane fx:id="inputTextScroll">
                    <TextFlow fx:id="inputText">
                        <padding>
                            <Insets fx:id="inputTextPadding" bottom="5.0"
                                left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0"/>
                        </padding>
                    </TextFlow>
                </ScrollPane>
            </center>
        </BorderPane>
    </SplitPane>
</Tab>
```

Now, I have a lot of text in it. Both the horizontal and the vertical scroll bars show.

What I need to do is to make a certain line visible by setting the `ScrollPane`'s `vvalue` (yes, two `v`s) so that this highlighted line appear as close as possible to the middle of the *visible portion* of the `TextFlow`.

But I cannot find a property on the `TextFlow` which tells me that. Its `.getHeight()` returns the total height of the embedded text, and this if of course not what I want...

The problem with the simple formula which is to divide the line number to display by the total number of lines is that it is messed up due to the horizontal scroll bar.

I'm at a loss. How do I obtain the visible height from the `TextFlow`, and only that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, answer to self...

I asked the same question elsewhere and got the response:

```
// inputTextScroll is the ScrollPane
final long visibleHeight = inputTextScroll.getViewportBounds().getHeight();
```

The beauty is that it does NOT include the scrollbars! Perfect.